# Crashed on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

**EDIT -  I have found, in my Procfile there was a space betwen my colon and my code, Heroku could not read this space, it's work now =).**

My app works perfectly on development, but crash after heroku pushing.

My console logs return me  :

> at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
> host=desolate-wildwood-76797.herokuapp.com
>
> request_id= fwd="fwd"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2018-05-22T23:15:39.338510+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>
> host=desolate-wildwood-76797.herokuapp.com
> request_id= fwd=""
>
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

But I have delete all favicon calls in my code, the others forums solutions don't work...

how handle that please ?

Comment: I don't think this is a favicon.ico issue,

Answer (score 1):

make sure your port is :

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```